# installing windows phone in VS 2010 Ultimate

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am fresher in windows phone. I want to work with windows phone. I have installed VS 2010 Ultimate in my Windows 8 32bit desktop. 
Now what to do.
I have downloaded a file named `WPSDK-7.1.1-KB2669191-x86.exe` which is 290MB in size.
Please tell me now what should i do to start....

Comment: Go to google and type getting started with Windows phone 7 Develeopment and click Search.  Then go to the links from the results. As easy as piano. Enjoy!!

Comment: I searched but i got confused about this things.

Comment: I think installing the SDK should add an entry in VS to create Windows Phone Applications.

Comment: it shows "installation required" error. i cant find the full sdk download link.

Answer (score 0):

[Getting started with developing for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Clean, clear and easy.

Comment: Then what is exactly your problem? What is it, that you want to know? How to run the .exe file? As Far I can read your question don't have a idea of how to start. The page I provided explains the steps which you need to follow to get everything set up.